# Set IFRAME's src on form load, avoiding load-race

Tags: javascript, iframe, dynamics-crm

I'm considering using an IFRAME in a form, and would like to know what's the correct way to avoid the traditional IFRAME load-race problem.

I thought I can simply set the IFRAME's `src` with a call inside the form's `OnLoad` event handler, since ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload)):

> The load event fires at the end of the document loading process. At
>   this point, all of the objects in the document are in the DOM, and all
>   the images, scripts, links and sub-frames have finished loading.

but [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328034.aspx) says (bold added):

> **Avoid using the OnLoad event.** IFRAMES and web resources load
>   asynchronously and the frame may not have finished loading before the
>   Onload event script finishes. This can cause the src property of the
>   IFRAME or web resource you have changed to be overwritten by the
>   default value of the IFRAME or web resource URL property.

If that so, what is the correct way to set the IFRAME's  `src`?

Note: I thought about using the IFRAME's OnReadyStateComplete event, meaning: Having an event handler in the form's script, set `src` when event fires, and use a flag to indicate that it was set (so that I won't enter an infinite load loop), but it seems like a bypass.

Comment: A self-redirecting "Loading..." web resource is what I do (I pass the URL as additional data, and leverage body onload ... YMMV)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no issue with the SetSrc function, I use the Form OnLoad event.

Some example code

```
// Get MAT IFrame control
var MATRepiFrame = Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get("IFRAME_MATGraph");
//Setup the URL
MATTargetUrl = serverUrl + '/crmreports/viewer/viewer.aspx?action=run&context=records&id=%7b092E3880-8266-E711-80DD-005056BD212E%7d&recordstype=1&records=' + accountId;
//Set the source
MATRepiFrame.setSrc(MATTargetUrl);
```

For more details see this webpage here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328034.aspx

Comment: The fact it works for you doesn't mean it is safe to use. The link you provided is the one I cited from, saying (if I understand it correctly) this is not safe.

Comment: CRM OnLoad is different to the HTML OnLoad event, also, typically if I am setting the URL of an iframe I would set the default source to about:blank.

Comment: If you look at the form.js code for setSrc, you can see it does a lot more than just change the source, it is kinda hard to read, but I believe it is doing this in a 'safe' way.